# Syntax: const CartContainer = ({ x, y, z }) => (

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Reading [a React/Redux example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/shopping-cart/src/containers/CartContainer.js) I stumble upon this piece of syntax

```
const CartContainer = ({ products, total, checkout }) => (
```

What is the `= ({x,y,z})` shorthand for?

Comment: This is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) combined with the new [arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: CartContainer is a function (likely a React Component) that takes one object as its only argument. Then creates 3 local variables in the function that are properties of the object that was passed in

Comment: [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/1529630)

Comment: @azium so this could be rewritten as `const CartContainer = function({products, total, checkout}) {};` and those 3 variables would be available in the function?

Comment: @softcode no; `function CartContainer ({products, total, checkout}) {…}`, which is the same as `function CartContainer (obj) { /* access obj.products, obj.total, and obj.checkout here */}`

Comment: @rayhowie HA! got it. thx man